# How to scrape for <span title>?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape indeed.com and when doing so I ran into a problem. When scraping for the titles of the positions on some results i get 'new' because there is a span before the position name labeled as 'new'. I have tried researching and trying different things i still havent got no where. So i come for help. The position names live within the span title tags but when i scrape for 'span' in some cases i obviously get the  'new' first because it grabs the first span it sees. I have tried to exclude it several ways but havent had any luck.

**Indeed Source Code:**

```
<div class="heading4 color-text-primary singleLineTitle tapItem-gutter">
<h2 class="jobTitle jobTitle-color-purple jobTitle-newJob">
<div class="new topLeft holisticNewBlue desktop">
<span class = "label">new</span>
</div>
<span title="Freight Stocker"> Freight Stocker </span>
</h2>
</div>
```

**Code I Tried:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extract(page):
headers = {''}
url = f'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?l=Bakersfield%2C%20CA&start={page}&vjk=42cee666fbd2fae9'
r = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
return soup

def transform(soup):
divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'heading4 color-text-primary singleLineTitle tapItem-gutter')

for item in divs:
    res = item.find('span').text
    print(res)       
return

c=extract(0)
transform(c)
```

**Results:**

new
Hourly Warehouse Ope
Immediate FT/PT Open
Service Cashier/Rece
new
Cannabis Sales Repreresentative
new
new
new
new
new

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code you have tried. Not as an image

Comment: also `indeed.com` questions answered a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CSS selector `.resultContent span[title]`, which will select all `<span>` that have a `title` attribute within the class `resultContent`.

To use a CSS selector, use the [`select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method instead of `.find()`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.select(".resultContent span[title]"):
    print(tag.text)
```